# Bulk MySQL update instead of PHP While loop

Tags: php, mysql, php-carbon, bulkupdate

I am using PHP code to update week ending date which is on a different day for each subdomain.  Each subdomain date range varies.

My current code uses a while loop to update the week end date.  This is very slow and I am looking for ideas to optimise it.

Here is my current code:

```
// Loop through and assign week end date to each user activity.
$nextWeek = $startDate;  // initialise while loop condition
while ($nextWeek <= $endDate) {
    $lastWeek = $nextWeek;
    $nextWeek = Carbon::parse($lastWeek)->addWeek(1)->format('Y-m-d');

    // update activity date to week end date
    $query = 'UPDATE r_active_user_activities 
                SET week_end_date = "' . $nextWeek . '"
                WHERE (activity_date > "' . $lastWeek . '" 
                    AND activity_date <= "' . $nextWeek . '"  
                    AND subdomain="' . $subdomain->subdomain . '" );';
    $db->statement($query);
}
```

Comment: Save all data array into temporary table by one query, then update the whole table in interest by second query.

Comment: I think this needs a much more clear description of your data model, before this becomes actually answerable …

Comment: You can also move the date calculation logic inside the query and run it for all sub-domains (if possible). As @04FS mentioned, the question needs more details to suggest a better alternate.

Answer (score -1):

Just append all those update queries in a php variable ($query) and execute that outside the while loop. something like this.

```
$nextWeek = $startDate;  // initialise while loop condition
$query = '';
while ($nextWeek <= $endDate) {
$lastWeek = $nextWeek;
$nextWeek = Carbon::parse($lastWeek)->addWeek(1)->format('Y-m-d');

// update activity date to week end date
$query .= 'UPDATE r_active_user_activities 
            SET week_end_date = "' . $nextWeek . '"
            WHERE (activity_date > "' . $lastWeek . '" 
                AND activity_date <= "' . $nextWeek . '"  
                AND subdomain="' . $subdomain->subdomain . '" );';
 }
$db->statement($query);
```